# Render Pass normal looks wrong

Tags: normals, render-passes

i try to use renderpass normals but i never get the result i would like to see.
Does anyone know if its possible to get a normal render from the renderpass?
left, render bad
right, vieport matcap good
[image]
doing it over material is not an option, to much materials to change.
it should be render pass!
no difference with cycles or eevee
no difference with srgb or none
looks like range is just covering half of the sapce